# JSON.parse() is returning a string when I need an object

Tags: node.js, json

I'm trying to use JSON.parse(scriptResult) to get this to turn into an object.

```
"scriptResult": "{\"AMD_Main_Toggle\":\"Off\",\"AMD_SilenceTimeout\":\"5000\",\"AMD_SpeechEnd\":\"1200\",\"AMD_SpeechStart\":\"2400\",\"AMD_Timeout\":\"30\",\"DND_EmailList\":\"\",\"DND_EmailToggle\":\"\",\"DND_SMSList\":\"\",\"DND_SMSToggle\":\"\",\"UVM_EmailList\":\"\",\"UVM_EmailToggle\":\"Yes\",\"UVM_SMSList\":\"\",\"UVM_SMSToggle\":\"Yes\",\"email\":\"Yes\",\"record\":\"Yes\",\"recordType\":\"record-from-ringing-dual\",\"recordingStatusCallback\":\"https://rpvrryjkt8.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/\",\"smsLookup\":\"Yes\",\"smsRecording\":\"\",\"transcribe\":\"\",\"whitepages\":\"Yes\"}"
```

This is the result I'm getting in the console.

```
{
    "AMD_Main_Toggle": "Off",
    "AMD_SilenceTimeout": 5000,
    "AMD_SpeechEnd": 1200,
    "AMD_SpeechStart": 2400,
    "AMD_Timeout": 30,
    "DND_EmailList": "",
    "DND_EmailToggle": "",
    "DND_SMSList": "",
    "DND_SMSToggle": "",
    "UVM_EmailList": "",
    "UVM_EmailToggle": "Yes",
    "UVM_SMSList": "",
    "UVM_SMSToggle": "Yes",
    "email": "Yes",
    "record": "Yes",
    "recordType": "record-from-ringing-dual",
    "recordingStatusCallback": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/",
    "smsLookup": "Yes",
    "smsRecording": "",
    "transcribe": "",
    "whitepages": "Yes"
}
```

I then use

```
console.log(typeof scriptResult)
```

and the console returns

```
string
```

I need scriptResult to be an object.

What am I missing?

updated-

```js
const scriptResult = "{\"AMD_Main_Toggle\":\"Off\",\"AMD_SilenceTimeout\":\"5000\",\"AMD_SpeechEnd\":\"1200\",\"AMD_SpeechStart\":\"2400\",\"AMD_Timeout\":\"30\",\"DND_EmailList\":\"\",\"DND_EmailToggle\":\"\",\"DND_SMSList\":\"\",\"DND_SMSToggle\":\"\",\"UVM_EmailList\":\"\",\"UVM_EmailToggle\":\"Yes\",\"UVM_SMSList\":\"\",\"UVM_SMSToggle\":\"Yes\",\"email\":\"Yes\",\"record\":\"Yes\",\"recordType\":\"record-from-ringing-dual\",\"recordingStatusCallback\":\"https://rpvrryjkt8.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/\",\"smsLookup\":\"Yes\",\"smsRecording\":\"\",\"transcribe\":\"\",\"whitepages\":\"Yes\"}";

    json = JSON.parse(scriptResult);
    console.log(typeof json);
    console.log(json);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2));
    console.log(typeof json)
```

Comment: Can you convert this to a JS embed (there's abutton for it in the editor)? It helps to show what's happenign

Comment: Before you parse scriptResult, it's indeed a string, not an object. Make sure you are checking results of JSON.parse

Comment: Ava- double checked that I'm checking the right results.  No dice.

Comment: It looks like the original JSON string contains an embedded JSON payload in `scriptResult`. So when you decode the original string, the embedded payload in `scriptResult` is still encoded. You may have to run `JSON.parse(scriptResult)` if you want to get its contents

Comment: You are logging the original script result, not the parsed valued.

Comment: noted, edited.  It works here but not on AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine to me.

```js
const scriptResult =  "{\"AMD_Main_Toggle\":\"Off\",\"AMD_SilenceTimeout\":\"5000\",\"AMD_SpeechEnd\":\"1200\",\"AMD_SpeechStart\":\"2400\",\"AMD_Timeout\":\"30\",\"DND_EmailList\":\"\",\"DND_EmailToggle\":\"\",\"DND_SMSList\":\"\",\"DND_SMSToggle\":\"\",\"UVM_EmailList\":\"\",\"UVM_EmailToggle\":\"Yes\",\"UVM_SMSList\":\"\",\"UVM_SMSToggle\":\"Yes\",\"email\":\"Yes\",\"record\":\"Yes\",\"recordType\":\"record-from-ringing-dual\",\"recordingStatusCallback\":\"https://rpvrryjkt8.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/\",\"smsLookup\":\"Yes\",\"smsRecording\":\"\",\"transcribe\":\"\",\"whitepages\":\"Yes\"}"; 

const json = JSON.parse(scriptResult); 
console.log(typeof scriptResult); 
console.log(typeof json);
```

Comment: I've got the same results when I run the code in isolation.

Comment: for some reason, it's still not returning an object when I'm running it with the rest of the application.